# Why it say to me that 'value' attribute is not a valid text area attribute in HTML5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I have the following problem.

I am working on a C#.NET web application and I am implementing some HTML 5 view that contains a some text area field. For example I have something like this:

```
<label for="nome">Description*:</label>
<textarea data-clear-btn="true" name="mitigatingStrategy.Description" id="description" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"  required="required" value="@Model.mitigatingStrategy.Description" rows="5" cols="40">Inserire qui la descrizione della nuova Mitigating Strategy</textarea>
```

It work well (the **@Model.mitigatingStrategy.Description is correctly setted) but Visual Studio sign this line and give me the following validation warning:

> **Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'value' is not a valid attribute of element 'textarea'**

So what is the problem? how can I fix it to obtain that my HTML is validated?

Comment: the `@Model.mitigatingStrategy.Description` should go in between your textarea tags: `<textarea>@Model.mitigatingStrategy.Description</textarea>`

Comment: Instead of the value attribute, it should be between the starting and closing brace

Comment: What do you mean by “It work well”? The `value` attribute is ignored by browsers, though it is stored in the DOM and can be addressed in a script.

Answer (score 6):

The value of a `textarea` goes between its tags:

```html
<textarea>@Model.mitigatingStrategy.Description</textarea>
```

Comment: and, using this solution, how can show  the default text to show in the textarea? Is it ok use data-value instead value?

Comment: @AndreaNobili  What is "Inserire qui la descrizione della nuova Mitigating Strategy" for you ?

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom field like `data-value` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

It says that the `value` attribute is invalid, because it is invalid in all HTML versions, for a `textarea` element.

It depends on the intended *effect* of the attribute what (if anything) you should use instead.